# Php select * where like

Tags: php, sql, search, select

Hi I am trying to get a search working for a site. It has 2 inputs for taking in info, one is a dropdown.

```
<div id="search">
<form action="projectsearchall.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h3>Search for an Item</h3>

<p>Keywords</p><p><input name="keywords" type="text" value="keywords"></p>


<p>Select A Location</p><p>

<select name="location" id="jumpMenu">
 <option>Any Location</option>
 <option>Antrim</option>
 <option>Armagh</option>
 <option>Carlow</option>
 <option>Cavan</option>


</select>
</p>
<p>
```

```
</form>
</div>
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to combine the 2 inputs to give a result, I can do it separately, but not working together to get a more accurate result.

php

```
$keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
$keylocation =$_POST['location'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

   //MySQL Database Connect
 include 'connect.php';
 //make sql query

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM projectitem where description  like '%$keywords%'  or item like '%$keywords%' or location like '%$keywords%'");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How come you're not using the $keylocation anywhere?

Comment: How do I select * where like for the 2 parameters : $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
$keylocation =$_POST['location'];

Comment: I'm not seeing the use of `$keylocation` in your query; not that you should, because this is actually dangerous without escaping it properly or using prepared statements.

Comment: I took it out as it wasn't working

Answer (score 4):

I think you may do some preprocessing, before running your query.

First off, you need to give your select options some sort of value to check against.

I don't know your exact database structure, but assuming that you're working with the select texts, you may want to try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM projectitem WHERE (description LIKE '%$keywords%' OR item LIKE '%$keywords%')";
```

This is your base query and running it right now will check against the keywords, but no location.

```
if($keylocation != "Any location") $query .= " AND location = '$keylocation'";
```

This last line will add the location as additional filter to your query. Run it, and see what it does. (I'm not sure about the string comparison there though)

Ah yes, as a final advice: Be sure to run your input through the escape function `mysqli_escape_string`. Otherwise you're opening yourself to SQL injections.

Comment: @CooPer Right there, in the `$query` assignment. The `WHERE` gets extended by the filter.

Comment: what happen if `$keyword` be `NULL` ? your query will be like this `SELECT * FROM projectitem WHERE (description LIKE '%%' OR item LIKE '%%')  AND location = '$keylocation'` its return all row !

Comment: @CooPer If the keyword is empty, it will return all results, which are matched. Just like it should, unless specified otherwise. An alternative would be checking the length of the keyword string and throwing an error if it's not at least a minimum amount of characters. Plus, a string can't be 'NULL' in this context...just empty.

Comment: maybe the keyword will be null **AND** keylocation is not null , the query must return data filtered by keylocation ! your answer is wrong

Comment: @CooPer To quote myself: `it will return all results, which are matched` -> My answer is not wrong. It will find all results by the first criteria `AND` then filter out those, who don't match the location. Boolean algebra: (x OR Y) AND Z equals (X AND Z) OR (Y AND Z)

Comment: ops! you change last `or` to `AND` sry :)

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually using the value of `$keylocation`; to narrow searches down, you need an `AND` instead of `OR`:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 'SELECT * FROM projectitem 
    where (description LIKE ? OR item LIKE ?) AND location LIKE ?');

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', "%$keywords%", "%$keywords%", "%$keylocation%");

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

// etc.
```

**Update**

Since the drop down may have "any location" you would need to dynamically change your query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM projectitem WHERE 1'; // base query

$types = ''; $vars = array();

if (!empty($keywords)) {
    $sql .= ' AND (description LIKE ? OR item LIKE ?)';
    $types .= 'ss';
    $vars[] = "%$keywords%";
    $vars[] = "%$keywords%";
}

if ($keylocation != 'Any Location') {
    $sql .= ' AND location LIKE ?';
    $types .= 's';
    $vars[] = $keylocation;
}

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
if ($types) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $types, $vars);
}
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: From reading his description it sounds like he wants `AND location[...]` , as he wants to be able to narrow the search down by location. I didn't DV.

Answer (score 0):

first you have sql injection

use `mysqli_real_escape_string`

if keywords for example is null your query will be like this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM projectitem where description  like '%%'  or item like '%%' or location like '%$keylocation%'");
```

and `description  like '%%'` return all row !

you must check data first

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM projectitem where 1=1 "
if($keywords)
  $query .= " AND ( description  like '%$keywords%' AND item like '%$keywords%' )";
if($keylocation)
  $query .= " AND location  like '%$keylocation%'";
```