# how can i make more intelligent search by php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table for places on database it contains two rows for title and description

I made a search by PHP and MYSQL like that

```
$select_place = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM places where title LIKE '%$searchname%' or description LIKE '%$searchname%'");
$num_place = $select_place->num_rows;

while ($rows_place = $select_place->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){

$id_place            = $rows_place ['id'];
$title_place         = $rows_place ['title'];
$description_place   = $rows_place ['description'];

echo "<p>{$title_place}</p><br>";

}
```

It works well, But, for example, if you search for the word tower if written in wrong way like twer or towr it doesn't work How can i make it more intelligent?

Comment: @Anant it doesn't work with me try to search for twr or something like that it  doesn't work

Comment: It might work in some configuration or version, but at least in my experience, it finds `tower` if you search for any part of that, such as `ower` or `tow`, but if you misspell the word, like `towr`, it doesn't find it.

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423905/php-select-where-like. It is useful for you

Comment: @Qirel If there is a way to make it a similar looking characters so if you did not find a search result

Comment: I'm not sure, honestly. I'm quite sure that there's a lot more work and algorithms behind it. I'm sure there's a guide on Google somewhere.

Comment: You can try to make a separate index row for each record that contains only unique words, and maybe omit umlauts etc., just off the top of my head. If you want to take it really far, you can save each search and the results that were chosen by the user, and create relations between the records that way, proposing alternate results even if they don't contain the current keyword. There's a lot of things you can do.

Answer (score 3):

One good option is to include MySQL `SOUNDEX()` function:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    places
WHERE
    title LIKE '%$searchname%'
    OR description LIKE '%$searchname%'
    OR SOUNDEX(title) = SOUNDEX('$searchname')
    OR SOUNDEX(description) = SOUNDEX('$searchname')
```

This will match both `towr` and `twer` from your example.

More can be found here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

Note that:

> This function, as currently implemented, is intended to work well with
>   strings that are in the English language only. Strings in other
>   languages may not produce reliable results.

Answer (score 1):

i found very useful way to do it

here it is

```
$searchname = stringsafe($_GET['search']);
$searchname2 = explode(" ", $searchname);
$query = "SELECT * FROM places WHERE ";

foreach ($searchname2 as $each) {
    $i++;

    if($i == 1){
        $query .= " title LIKE '%$each%'
    OR description LIKE '%$each%'
    OR SOUNDEX(title) = SOUNDEX('$each')
    OR SOUNDEX(description) = SOUNDEX('$each')";
    }else{
        $query .= " OR title LIKE '%$each%'
    OR description LIKE '%$each%'
    OR SOUNDEX(title) = SOUNDEX('$each')
    OR SOUNDEX(description) = SOUNDEX('$each')";
    }
}

$select_place = $mysqli->query("$query limit 20");
$num_place = $select_place->num_rows;

if($num_place == 0){
    echo "<div class='message-no'>No results</div>";
}
else{

while ($rows_place = $select_place->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){

$id_place            = $rows_place ['id'];
$title_place         = $rows_place ['title'];
$description_place   = $rows_place ['description'];

echo $title_place."<br>";

}
```

Comment: can you update this code because this will throw an error in future and try to make this statement into prepared statement