# SQL query in php fetch database

Tags: php

I am struggling to find a way to get rows from a database, based on two columns, firstName and lastName according to the search bar.

The issue is on WHERE/LIKE operators and ' ".

I am using this code below:

```
$search = $_POST["search"];
$query = "SELECT p.id, p.lastName, p.firstName, p.jobTitle, p.email, d.name as department, l.name as location 
            FROM personnel p 
            LEFT JOIN department d ON (d.id = p.departmentID) 
            LEFT JOIN location l ON (l.id = d.locationID) 
            WHERE p.firstName LIKE '%".$search."%' 
                OR p.lastName LIKE '%".$search."%'";
```

This code it's working just for one value, for example if I remove `OR p.lastName LIKE '%".$search."%'`.

Comment: It should work the same when searching two columns as searching one.

Comment: I have found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423905/php-select-where-like

...WHERE (p.firstName LIKE '%$search%') OR (p.lastName LIKE '%$search%')";

Comment: It probably won't solve this problem, but you should use a prepared query with parameters to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: Which answer there solved it? I don't think you want to use `AND` instead of `OR`. And you shouldn't use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, you should use a prepared statement.

Comment: You only need parentheses if you're mixing `AND` and `OR` in the condition. You don't need it with just `OR`.